# Como deletar pastas, subpastas e arquivos?

Tags: php

Utilizando meu exemplo abaixo, consigo deletar uma pasta e os arquivos contidos nela:

```
 $uploaddir = "../img/uploads/".$destino_sa."/";
 $dir_contents = scandir($uploaddir);

 if(is_dir($uploaddir)) {
   foreach($dir_contents as $content) {
     unlink($uploaddir.'/'.$content);
     rmdir($uploaddir);
   }
 }
```

Porém, ao utilizar o mesmo exemplo para deletar uma pasta que contém uma subpasta e seus arquivos, não obtenho êxito:

```
$uploaddir2 = "../img/uploads/hoteis/".$id_destino2."/".$destino_sa2."/";
$dir_contents2 = scandir($uploaddir);

 if(is_dir($uploaddir2)) {
   foreach($dir_contents2 as $content2) {
     unlink($uploaddir2.'/'.$content2);
     rmdir($uploaddir2);
   }
 }
```

Vê-se então que `$destino` e `$destino2` são locais completamente diferentes, sendo o último, que está me causando problemas na hora de ser removido. Segue um exemplo do que quero remover através do `$destino2`:

```
../img/uploads/hoteis/3/hotel_emiliano/
```

- Pasta **hotel_emiliano** e seu conteúdo
- Pasta **3** e seu conteúdo, no caso a pasta `hotel_emiliano`

Como devo proceder?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[No manual do PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rmdir.php) tem um [exemplo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rmdir.php#110489) de função recursiva que faz isso (apesar de usar o operador ternário [de uma maneira que eu não gosto](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rmdir.php#110489)):

```
public static function delTree($dir) { 
  $files = array_diff(scandir($dir), array('.','..')); 
  foreach ($files as $file) { 
    (is_dir("$dir/$file")) ? delTree("$dir/$file") : unlink("$dir/$file"); 
  } 
  return rmdir($dir); 
}
```

No seu caso, você pode usar assim:

```
delTree('../img/uploads/hoteis/3/');
```

Answer (score 4):

Você também pode usar [SPL Iterators Class](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/spl.iterators.php) com [RecursiveIteratorIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php) e [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php) diponíveis apartir do  PHP 5.3.0, veja:

```
 $directory = 'hotel_emiliano';

 foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($directory,FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS), RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST) as $file){
    $file->isFile() ? unlink($file->getPathname()) : rmdir($file->getPathname());
 }
 rmdir($directory);
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternativamente, as respostas postadas, pode-se usar as funções de Shell.

Em ambiente Linux, para remover um diretório e todo o seu conteúdo:

```
ls | xargs rm -rf
```

Em ambiente Windows

```
RMDIR \"drive_letter:\path\of\directory\" /S /Q
```

No PHP, sob Linux, ficaria assim:

```
// Caminho do diretório
$path = '/path/of/directory/';
// Muda para o diretório
chdir($path);
// Executa o comando sob o diretório
exec('ls | xargs rm -rf');
// Apaga a pasta que deve estar vazia, nesse ponto.
rmdir($path);
```

Sob Windows

```
exec('RMDIR \"drive_letter:\path\of\directory\" /S /Q');
```

Esse método é mais performático do que usar recursividade em funções do PHP, pois é o sistema operacional que fará o trabalho.

Obviamente, necessita de permissões adequadas para tal operação.
Também necessita verificar se chdir() retorna false ou true antes de prosseguir com o exec().

Note que o exemplo acima é para fins didáticos e os comandos variam de acordo com o Sistema Operacional e suas respectivas distribuições.

Comment: Embora seja mais performático, não recomendo nem um pouco utilizar funções como `exec()` ou `eval()` em casos simples, por questões de segurança.

Comment: A preocupação com a segurança independente da complexidade do caso.