# Listar Pastas e excluir arquivos dentro das mesmas de uma vez só

Tags: php

Minha ideia é que eu conseguisse apagar todos os arquivos dentro das pastas de uma vez só ou por período (exemplo, a cada 5 meses me listar esses arquivos dentro do período).

Eu consegui listar todas as pastas e clicando nelas consigo visualizar os arquivos.

Alguém poderia sanar com algum exemplo pra poder dar continuidade a partir do código PHP abaixo?

EDIT: Basicamente, seria listar todas as pastas e apagar todos os arquivos dentro das pastas existente de uma vez só.

Agradeço desde já!

CÓDIGO:

```
<?php
    $dir = "./";
    foreach (glob ($dir."*", GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $pastas) {
        if (is_dir ($pastas)) {
        echo "Motorista: ";
            echo str_replace ( $dir,"",$pastas)." <img style='width: 20px; height: 20px;' src=\"icon-motorista.png\"/> - <a href=\"$pastas\">Olhar pasta</a><br />";
                        echo "";
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como deletar pastas, subpastas e arquivos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15144/como-deletar-pastas-subpastas-e-arquivos)

Comment: No meu caso seria percorrer em todas as pastas existentes e apagar todos os arquivos dentro dessas pastas.Não quero apagar as pastas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso é bem simples vc só precisa usar outro `glob()` dentro do primeiro loop, para criar outro loop e excluir todos os arquivos das subpastas.

```
## lista as pastas do diretorio atual
foreach(glob('./*', GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $i){
    ## lista e apaga todos os arquivos das subpastas
    foreach(glob($i.'/*') as $e){
        unlink($e);
    }
}
```

Edit:

```
$date = "27-4-2019";

## checa a data
if(date("d-m-Y") == date("d-m-Y", strtotime($date.'+5 Month')));
    foreach(glob('./*', GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $i){
        foreach(glob($i.'/*') as $e){
            unlink($e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH) in C:\xampp\htdocs\chametaxi\motorista\admin\uploads\teste.php on line 5

dá esse erro, mas como eu poderia colocar isso funcional naquele código acima?

Comment: Eu editei o código, mas é a mesma coisa, vc disse que queria apagar todos os arquivos das subpastas, e é isso que o código acima vai fazer, então pq vc iria querer dar `echo` para o link das pastas?

Comment: Era mais pra ter a certeza de que as pastas estariam "criadas" ainda. Obrigado pela ajuda!
Ainda nesse código, é possível colocar um tempo com alert para apagar os arquivos?
Ex: Abri a página e me dá um alert "Somente abra este link após 5 meses" e colocar uma condição de data pra quando for abrir de novo não apagar os arquivos e sim após a data especificada?

Comment: Sim, é possivel, eu editei o código. Ma em relação ao `alert()` vc tem que da uma pesquisada sobre ajax ou javascript pra fazer tudo isso.

Comment: A date é fixa né? então eu teria que ficar editando essa data fixa pro dia atual que for excluir? teoricamente isso que impede se caso abrir de novo, não exclua?

Comment: vc so tem que alterar o valor da variavel `$data` para o dia em que vc quer que inicie a contagem (dia atual + 5 meses).

Answer (score 0):

Tente isto:

```
<?php
    function excluir($dir){
        if(is_file($dir)){
            return unlink($dir);
        }elseif(is_dir($dir)){
            $files = array_diff(scandir($dir), array('.','..'));
            foreach ($files as $file){
                (is_dir("$dir/$file")) ? excluir("$dir/$file") : unlink("$dir/$file");
            };
            //return rmdir($dir); //remova caso queira apaga a pasta
        };
    };
    excluir("./"); //coloque aqui o diretório que deseja excluir.
?>
```